# Transistor Familiarization

Tags: transistors, potentiometer

Having trouble with this problem . Where will be the end of the arrow on the transistor be connected (upper right) ..[image]

[image]

Comment: If you are genuinely learning, at least learn the correct terms,"arrow on the transistor" shows no interest.

Comment: Why did you bother adding the table? Did you think that we would do your homework for you?

Comment: Just want to be guided accordingly .. on the table, i have 2 Vebs .. how am I gonna get it?

Comment: No, you don't. Read closer.

Comment: scanned text virtually unreadable.  -1

Answer (score 1):

It is supposed to be left unconnected.

This circuit is for testing just the base-collector diode.

Answer (score 0):

Nowhere.

A BJT acts not only as a transistor as normal but also a pair of diodes, both pointing either towards or away from the base.